# Rotate quantum state by a given angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-computer, bloch-sphere

Is there any gates that allow to rotate quantum state by a given angle $\theta$ in XZ plane? I'd like to move from state
$$|\psi\rangle =  |0\rangle$$ to state $$|\psi\rangle = {1 \over{\sqrt2}}  |0\rangle+{1 \over{\sqrt2}} |1\rangle$$
what I can do by using Hadamard gate but after beeing in this state I'd like to move to the state:
$$|\psi\rangle =  |1\rangle$$
or do it but instead of angle $\pi \over 2$ use angle $\pi \over 4$.

Comment: Do you know about the rotation operator $e^{-i\mathbf{\sigma\cdot\hat{n}}\frac{\phi}{2}}$?

Comment: What you describe is a rotation in the XZ-plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gate
$$
R_y(\phi):=\exp[-i\sigma_y \phi/2] = \left(\begin{matrix}
\cos\phi/2&\sin\phi/2\\-\sin\phi/2&\cos\phi/2\end{matrix}\right)
$$
(with $\sigma_y$ the Pauli $y$ matrix) describes a rotation about the y-axis, i.e., in the XZ-plane, by an angle of $\phi$. (Up to a global phase, which you can compensate for if you want.)

You can easily check that it does what you ask for.

Comment: @user Global phases don't matter.  They describe the same state.